# Posting Ajax Data to PHP REST SERVICE

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, post

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions I have tried  work, I wrote a php rest service which I'm hosting on a server, I used advanced rest client data on chrome to test my rest service and it works, it posts data to the database, but when I wrote my own client in an ajax post below the browser complains of

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I have tried adding a header to my php code still doesn't work i get another error..., I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong?

```
 >// MY PHP REST SERVICE  
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "xxxx";
 $dbname = "xxx";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
 // Get data
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $surname = $_POST['surname'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 // Insert data into data base
 $sql = "INSERT INTO UserData.register (name, surname, email, password)
 VALUES  ('$name', '$surname', '$email','$password')";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $json = array("status" => 1000, "msg" => "Done User added!");
  } else {
   $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error adding user!");
  }
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($json);
 $conn->close();
 }



 > //MY java script ajax client doing the posting.

   <script type="text/javascript">        
      function RegisterUser() {

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var surname = $("#surname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/signup.php",
            data: '{"name":"' + name + '","surname":"' + surname +    '","email":"' + email + '","password":"' + password + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d)
                         }

        });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using .htaccess file
`Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"`

CORS guide is [here](http://enable-cors.org/) which lists all the possible ways to solve the problem regarding CORS.